# How to prove that $|\mathcal{F}|\leq 2^{n-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of an $n$-element set $X$. A family is intersecting iff any two of its sets have a non-empty intersection.

How can I prove that if $\mathcal{F}$ is an intersecting family, then $|\mathcal{F}|\leq 2^{n-1}$? How can I show that there is an intersecting family $\mathcal{F}'$ containing $\mathcal{F}$ such that $|\mathcal{F}'| = 2^{n−1}$.

What I've tried: Let $(Y,Z)$ be any partition of $X$. Then at most one of $Y$ and $Z$ can contain an
element of $\mathcal{F}$ . If neither of them does, then both $Y$ and $Z$ are blocking sets. So, if
we let $\mathcal{F}'$ consist of all sets containing a member of $\mathcal{F}$ together with one of each
complementary pair of blocking sets, then $\mathcal{F}'$ contains one of each complementary pair of sets. Furthermore, since $\mathcal{F}$  is intersecting, then any two sets which contain members
of $\mathcal{F}$  must intersect; a set containing a member of $\mathcal{F}$  intersects each blocking
set; and, if we choose the larger of each pair of blocking sets,
then any two of the chosen blocking sets intersect. So we have an intersecting family containing $\mathcal{F}$. But why $|\mathcal{F}'|=2^{n-1}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: It might help to first state the definition of an intersecting family.

Comment: @Om3ga You are completely right. I've just added my thought. Thank you.

Comment: @J.G. A family is intersecting if any two of its sets have a non-empty
intersection.

Comment: Think about pairs of sets which are complements to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. You meant to say at most one of $Y$ and $Z$ can _be_ an element of $\mathcal{F}$. It looks like the only insight you're missing is (why) $X$ has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: @hardmath that last comment is not quite right. given an intersecting family $F$, let $G$ be an intersecting family of maximal possible size containing $F$. if $G$ does not have size $2^{n-1}$, then there exists some $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\notin G$ and $A^c\notin G$. by maximality of $G$, neither $G\cup\{A\}$ nor $G\cup\{A^c\}$ is intersecting, so there exist $C,D\in G$ such that $A\cap C=A^c\cap D=\varnothing$. but then $C\cap D=\varnothing$, contradicting that $G$ is intersecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Write as $V$ the $n$-element set. Then there are $2^n$ subsets of $V$, and furthermore those $2^n$ subsets of $V$ can be partitioned into $2^{n-1}$ pairs $\{S,\bar{S}\}$, where $\bar{S}$ is the complement of $S$. If $\cal{F}$ is intersecting however, then for each $S \in \cal{F}$, its complement $\bar{S}$ in $V$ is not in $\cal{F}$, equivalently, only one of $S$, $\bar{S}$ can be in $\cal{F}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I have a question: how can I define $\mathcal{F}'$ then? Can I define $\mathcal{F}'$ this way: $\mathcal{F}'=\{ S\; |\; \{ S,\bar{S}\}\; \text{is a partition of}\;  V$? Then $\mathcal{F}'$ is not intersecting itself.

Comment: You mean we need to choose just either $S$ or $\bar{S}$ for which $\{ S,\bar{S}\}$ is a partition of $V$, then since $\mathcal{F}$ is not intersecting, so $\mathcal{F}'$ contains $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Only one of $S$, $\bar{S}$ can be in $\cal{F}$. So only half of the $2^n$ subsets of $V$ can be in $\cal{F}$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. I understood that $|\mathcal{F}|\leq 2^{n-1}$. But what is $\mathcal{F}'$ containing $\mathcal{F}$? I've taken $\mathcal{F}'$ a family including only one of $S,\bar{S}$ for which $\{ S,\bar{S}\}$ is a partition of $V$ but is $\mathcal{F}'$ intersecting?